# how to access an XML file stored in the same directory as the DLL when DLL is installed in GAC

Tags: c#

I have a dll project which have an xml file. [content of that dll project]
I have installed that dll in My GAC. In some method of that dll I needed to load that xml file. but I can't able to find the path or way by which I can load that xml,

My xml files looks like following

```
<Data>
  <add key="Hostname" value="192.XXX.XXX.111" />
  <add key="UserName" value="root123" />
  <add key="Password" value="admin1234" />  

  <add key="SFTP_IncomingFileFolder" value="/root/Inbox/" />
  <add key="SFTP_ArchivedFileFolder" value="/root/Archived/" />
  <add key="SFTP_OutGoingFileFolder" value="/root/Outbox/" />


  <add key="Local_IncomingFileFolder" value="D:\phpFiles2\Inbox\" />
  <add key="Local_OutgoingFileFolder" value="D:\phpFiles2\Outbox\" />
  <add key="Local_OutgoingArchive" value="D:\phpFiles2\Archived\" />

  <add key="ApplicationFolderPath" value="D:\SFTP_Installation\" /><!-- where WinSCP.exe resides-->
</Data>
```

Comment: Doesn't `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)` work?

Comment: It is something Like
file:\C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyAssemblyConnector\1.0.0.0__c5757f9909ed318b

Comment: So can't you use that path and append the filename of the XML file to it?

Comment: So basically, your question is how to access an XML file stored in the same directory as the DLL, after you've moved the DLL, but not the XML file?

Comment: My xml is in the same directory where My dll is placed.

Comment: Remember I need to change the value in xml file. So I can't use it as embeded resource

Comment: Oh? So your XML file is stored in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyAssemblyConnector\1.0.0.0__c5757f9909ed318b too?

Comment: How can I store it there. I am simply dragging my .dll to install

Comment: Mydll methods are called by php. I have to have some configurable settings which i have stored in that xml file. http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Comment: You said you already did. You specifically claimed that your XML is in the same directory where your DLL is placed. You also indicated that your DLL is placed in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyAssemblyConnector\1.0.0.0__c5757f9909ed318b. If your XML file is not already there, then your XML file is **not** in the same directory where your DLL is placed. Anyway, you can't. Depending on your reason for wanting this, other approaches may work. You'd need to edit your question to give some impression of the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from the comments:

You cannot. When you install a DLL in the GAC, ***only*** that DLL gets copied into the GAC. You cannot avoid this, at least not in any supported way.

You mentioned in the comments that you want to let your DLL read configuration options. Some workable alternatives for that:

- Store the settings in the registry.
- Store the settings in the user profile directory.
- Store the settings in C:\ProgramData.
- Let the calling program (your PHP script) control the settings, and let that calling program read the settings from a file in the program's directory.

None of those options require any files in the same directory as your DLL.

Comment: Thanks hvd. It's my first instance that there is a need of exposing a dll which is not called by .net otherwise i could have used configuration manager and set the setting in calling program. Above mentioned solutions all required extra setting while i were just thinking of providing my dll package, install it in GAC and nothing else

Comment: Well, you could store default settings in the DLL directly, and only save to one of the other locations when you change a setting from the default. That way, you don't need any additional installation step, everything just works, with the default settings anyway. The default .NET "Settings" functionality supports this, as should most other configuration libraries.

Comment: It's basically nothing default there. I have copied my xml setting in the question. I am basically desiging a utility for SFTP download via winscp library. Obviously My sftp account, incoming and outgoing path will be different in different environments

Comment: In that case I'd opt for the fourth bullet point in my answer: let the PHP script pass the configuration to the .NET library. Or a minor adaptation of that: let the PHP script pass in the path to the XML file, so that the .NET library knows where to look.

Comment: At the moment I have done it like you have suggested. My xml file name with path is now input by php script